# Group cases based on id and other variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having trouble restricting a dataset based on an ifelse condition.

This is an example of my dataframe:

```
structure(list(id = c(111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112), se = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3), pe = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I need to select cases that have the same id and pe

End table should be this:

```
  id     se   pe
    112     1    1  
    112     2    1    
    112     3    1
```

Comment: one option: `subset(df, id == 112 & pe == 1)`

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen thanks yes, that is a good solution but unfortunately if have 211 id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach using `dplyr`. You can compute flags to determine the number of unique elements and then filter. The flags are `nid` and `npe`. Here the code with `df` your `dput()` data:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(nid = n_distinct(id),npe = n_distinct(pe)) %>%
  filter(nid==1 & npe==1) %>% select(-c(nid,npe))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [1]
     id    se    pe
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   112     1     1
2   112     2     1
3   112     3     1
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also do this without creating/deleting new columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(se) == 1 | n_distinct(pe) == 1)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [1]
#     id    se    pe
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   112     1     1
#2   112     2     1
#3   112     3     1
```